# How can I filter a get request to a json-server with specific search queries?

Tags: javascript, json, json-server

I have installed a Json-Server. Get-Requests to this server are delivering the expected data but now I want to add some search queries to my request. But the result is still the same. I don't know whats my mistake here.

Here is my request:
http://localhost:3000/people?age=22

I also tried it with:
http://localhost:3000/people?customer.age=22 but the result is still all data.

Thats my JSON-File:

```
 {
  "customer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Stefan Winkler",
      "phone_number": "017692601589",
      "age": "22",
      "education": "High School"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Christoph Huber",
      "phone_number": "094462649",
      "age": "42",
      "education": "nothing"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Michael Unholer",
      "phone_number": "093862649",
      "age": "12",
      "education": "Realschule"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it's a node.js server i installed json-server(https://github.com/typicode/json-server) via npm

Comment: Seems to work as expected on their example: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?address.street=Victor%20Plains But your source data is an object and it should be an array

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:3000/customer?age=22 ? Is that you full DB, or the result that you get with a different query ?

Answer (score 20):

try

http://localhost:3000/customer?age=22

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Stefan Winkler",
    "phone_number": "017692601589",
    "age": "22",
    "education": "High School"
  }
]
```

http://localhost:3000/customer?name_like=rist

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Christoph Huber",
    "phone_number": "094462649",
    "age": "42",
    "education": "nothing"
  }
]
```

Comment: How can you filter by two arguments, for instance name_like or age_like

Comment: @MeatBALL You can use "&" to append to query params. For example, http://localhost:3000/customer?name_like=rist&education_like=high

Comment: How can I filter by a union of two arguments, for instance all items where title or description contains 'climate'?
title_like=climate|description_like=climate is not working.